# Batch Script to Extract Email Addresses From Target Folder/File

Tags: email, batch-file, cmd, extract

**Program:** Command Prompt (CMD) batch script

I have a folder filled with lots of files. Within those files are lots of email addresses mixed with other misc. text junk. I'd like a way to extract these email addresses from **each** file and create a new file (.txt) with each one listed as clearly as possible.

I have already spent hours finding a decent Regular Expression 'code': "**[.A-Z-_]*@[.A-Z-_]***"

This expression was derived from what seems to amazingly be the ONLY other forum thread on this topic that Google can detect - which I find astounding. That thread can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911482/extract-email-from-text-file-using-batch-job

On that thread, some guy named **Hand-E-Food** created the below .bat script to extract email addresses from a selected file/folder:

```
@Echo Off
For /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('FindStr /R /I "[\.A-Z\-_]*@[\.A-Z\-_]*" "results.txt"') Do Call :ExtractEmail "%%A"
Exit /B

:ExtractEmail
Set "Email=%~1"
Set "Email=%Email:*<=%"
Set "Temp=%Email:*>=>%"
Call Set "Email=%%Email:%Temp%=%%"
Echo %Email%>emails.txt
Exit /B
```

Amazingly, he neglected to fully error-test his code and sadly it does not work - as was mentioned by the original poster. Annoyingly, he never responded to correct his mistake and now the topic is closed.

Which brings us here: a new topic, asking the same question that should have been answered in 2011 but wasn't. So if anyone can help out with what I imagine is probably a rather simple code for what I would *think* was an extremely useful ability, please lend us your expertise.

**P.S.** Please do not be like **Hand-E-Food** and neglect to double-check that your code even works. Also, I have a small amount of experience in Command Prompt, however many users who look at this thread will have NO experience whatsoever, so please use some notation in your code to explain - at least slightly - what's going on.

Remember: None of us knew everything we know now, and it was only through kind people who explained, **fully**, to us how to do something that we ever learned in the first place. Please explain **fully**.

Thanks a bunch,

StepbyStep

Comment: _"sadly it does not work"_ -- what is the expected result, and what do you get instead?

Comment: Basically the end result of his batch script creates a file called "emails.txt" which has only 1 line of output: "ECHO is off." The rest of the file is completely blank and does not include any of the email addresses I know to be present. I have error-tested it myself by simply using the code: FindStr /R /I "[\.A-Z\-_]*@[\.A-Z\-_]*  in command prompt will result in the correct output. So, basically, everything works except for the code he wrote in the :ExtractEmail function. The expected result is that it lists (preferably on a new line) all of the found email addresses.

Comment: This is not a suitable task for a batch file imo, hence few links. Linked code only matches whole lines with an address is that what you want?  - The line `Echo %Email%>emails.txt` uses a single `>` which will overwrite `emails.txt` so instead you want to use `Echo %Email% >> emails.txt` to *append*. The code in `ExtractEmail` *seems* to expect `findstr` to emit individual addresses delimited by `>*` and `<*` which is not the case, the file is thus empty because `Call Set "Email=%%Email:%Temp%=%%"` makes `%Email%` empty so `Echo %Email%` calls echo with no argument which prints `echo is off`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. No, outputting the whole line is annoying, but I had figured that would be a later issue to tackle. I'm assuming, then, that there is no real way around this when using a batch script? Also, thanks for the info regarding how to fix the script. I don't have the time right now, but I'm assuming I should be able to fix it later - thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have you actually tested that regular expression for **FAILURE** with `findstr`? I keep passing it illegal email addresses like `@gmail.com`, and it keeps letting them pass.

Answer (score 4):

Well, here's an alternative script that should do the trick:

```
@echo off
set INPUT_FILE=results.txt
set OUTPUT_FILE=emails.txt
set "REGEXP=[\.A-Z\-_][\.A-Z\-_]*@[\.A-Z\-_][\.A-Z\-_]*"
>nul copy nul %OUTPUT_FILE%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do for %%b in (%%a) do (
    for /f %%z in ('echo %%b ^| findstr /R /I "%REGEXP%"') do (
        echo %%z >> %OUTPUT_FILE%
    )
)
```

It's quite simple: the outer loop iterates over space-delimited strings in each line in `INPUT_FILE`, and the inner loop filters emails using your regular expression and appends them to `OUTPUT_FILE`.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** I improved the regular expression so that it captures an e-mail pattern more accurately. It is still not perfect, but you can check out [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) if you're interested in even better expressions.

Comment: I don't know, the only way for me to make that regular expression to fail is to remove the @ symbol from the stream. Even this test succeeds: `echo bla bla 34ubv::fiddle? @gmail.com?yfyj  htfy | findst
r /R /I "[\.A-Z\-_]*@[\.A-Z\-_]*"` echoing the string right back.

Comment: I used the OP's regexp and didn't put extra thought in it, but now I improved it. Please see my updated answer. It doesn't handle `?` ub emails though.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep at you, but testing your new REGEX against improper domain names like `x@com` still fails.

Comment: I believe it's a minor issue, but I added [this reference site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) that suggests more accurate expressions.